# Create travel event in local time across timezones. Google api v3

Tags: google-calendar-api

I know this has been asked a lot of times but I think a resolution is still not provided.

Google calendar api v3:

Regardless of programming language used:
If you create travelling event, a flight from A to B. You want the departure and arrival times in A and B to always show in local time A and B. Regardless where you are.

I know this also depends on the type (android, ios) and settings on your device.
Does anyone has a conceptual idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the calendar API v3 you can specify a separate timezone for start and end of an event. See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events